# How to add horizontal as well as vertical lines in listView android

Tags: android, listview

I want custom listview BUT remember i need to stretch listview lines vertical and horizontal even if there is not list item. I try using list divider for horizontal lines and use vertical lines in list_item.xml but it shows lines depends upon the size of array means if my ArrayList has 5 objects then it shows only 5 lines both vertical and horizontal.

Comment: Here is Image of required thing 

http://prntscr.com/7sj943

Comment: Have a condition to check if the array size is 0 and inflate another layout like the one you posted

Comment: But what if i have array size==1 and vertical and horizontal lines still not fill complete screens.

Comment: You can either inflate listviewitems(to fill the complete page) on the page in the beginning itself or you can set the background of the list view as this image.